# Problem rendering first 2 objects in three.js

Tags: javascript, function, three.js, render, renderer

everything works fine but sphere and box geometry dont show, plane works fine too! does anyone have a clue? i suspect something wrong maybe in the render function or animation frame, im fairly new to three.js and cant seem to know why the scene wont show the other geometry, i tried different materials, rotation, clear color, etc

```
var renderer,
        scene,
        camera,
        myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

    //RENDERER
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: myCanvas,
      antialias: true,
    });
  renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);        //device pixel ratio
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);                //canvas size

  //CAMERA
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 300, 10000)
  //SCENE
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  //LIGHT
  var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffff, 0.5)
  scene.add(light);

  var light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffff, 0.5)
  scene.add(light1);

  //MATERIAL

  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      color: 0xF3FFE2,
      lightMap: null,
      lightMapIntensity: 1,
      emissive: 0x000000,
      emissiveMap: null,
      emissiveIntensity: 1,
      specularMap: null
    });

  //GEOMETRY

  var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 100, 100);
    var mesh = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.z = -1000;
    mesh.position.x = -100;
    scene.add(mesh);


  var geometry2 = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 20, 20);
    var mesh2 = new THREE.Points(geometry2, material);
    mesh2.position.z = -1000;
    mesh2.position.x = 100;
    scene.add(mesh2);

  var geometry3 =  new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10000, 10000, 100, 100);
    var mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry3, material);
    mesh3.rotation.x = -90 * Math.PI / 180;
    mesh3.position.y = -100;
    scene.add(mesh3);

  //RENDER LOOP

  render();



      function render() {

        mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
        mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;



        renderer.render(scene, camera);

        requestAnimationFrame(render);
      }
```

Comment: Do you want those sphere and box as points? If so, then use the respective material `PointsMaterial` for those objects. If you want them as solid objects, then use `THREE.Mesh` instead of `THREE.Points` on them.

Comment: @wwitshadows Please, mark the question as answer accepted if it solved your initial problem, this way will also help other users to know it was the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried your code, everything is ok but the 2 objects need to be `THREE.Mesh`

```
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 100, 100);
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.z = -1000;
    mesh.position.x = -100;
    scene.add(mesh);


    var geometry2 = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 20, 20);
    var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material);
    mesh2.position.z = -1000;
    mesh2.position.x = 100;
    scene.add(mesh2);
```

[image]